# Java Generics - Not Applicable for the Arguments

Tags: java, generics, serialization

I have a class that has a field of getting a `Serializer`. `valueSelializer` will accept a Serializer class which has a `SpecificRecordBase` as its arguments.

```
@Builder
@Data
public class FactoryProperties<T extends SpecificRecordBase> {

    private Serializer<?> keySerializer;

    private Serializer<T> valueSerializer;
}
```

However when I create a method to input the default value

```
public <T extends SpecificRecordBase> FactoryPropertiesBuilder<T> defaultFactoryProperties(
        Class<T> targetType) {
    return FactoryProperties.builder()
            .keySerializer(new StringSerializer())
            .valueSerializer(new MySerializer<T>());
}
```

```
public class MySerializer<T extends SpecificRecordBase> implements Serializer<T>
```

I am encountering an error says `Type mismatch: cannot convert from FactoryProperties.FactoryPropertiesBuilder<SpecificRecordBase> to FactoryProperties.FactoryPropertiesBuilder<T>`

Based on my understanding `T` is already a `SpecificRecordBase`. Can someone please enlighten me whats wrong with the code and the logic?

Comment: Does `FactoryProperties.builder<T>()` work?

Comment: @dan1st tried adding it, it gave me an error of `Syntax error on token "(", Expression expected after this token`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`builder` is a generic method. If you delombok it, you'll see it's:

```
public static <T extends SpecificRecordBase> FactoryPropertiesBuilder<T> builder() {
    return new FactoryPropertiesBuilder<T>();
}
```

You haven't specified a generic type parameter for the `builder` call, so the compiler needs to infer a type for `T`. Note that it hasn't got a lot of information here. It won't go check the `valueSerializer` call and see that you actually want `T` (type parameter of `builder`) to be `T` (type parameter of `defaultFactoryProperties`).

So the compiler just infers `T` to be its bound - `SpecificRecordBase`. This is why `valueSerializer` expects a `Serializer<SpecificRecordBase>`.

You should specify the type parameter explicitly:

```
return FactoryProperties.<T>builder()
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining in details. Been stuck here for hours. Thank you